# Consultando em Eloquent

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

Eu tenho um script em laravel que no eloquent preciso colocar uma condição no eloquent ao invés de selecionar todos conforme está,preciso que selecione de acordo com o id do usuário.

Verifiquei que devo usar o Event::find ao invés de Event:all(),mas está retornando erro.

```
$events = [];
            $data = Event::all();
            if($data->count()) {
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $events[] = Calendar::event(
                        $value->title,
                        true,
                        new \DateTime($value->start_date),
                        new \DateTime($value->end_date.' +1 day'),
                        null,
                        // Add color and link on event
                     [
                         'color' => '#ff0000',
                         'url' => '#',
                     ]
                    );
                }
            }
            $calendar = Calendar::addEvents($events);
```

Comment: Sugiro que de uma olhada na documentação do eloquent/laravel https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent. Já adiantando, a função find tem como paramento um inteiro que seria o id (Event::find(1)) definido na sua tabela ou uma array de inteiros(Event::find([1, 2, 3])).

Comment: Passe um id(em inteiro) no lugar da string... caso o id que deseja buscar seja o 1 seria Event::find(1);

Comment: Meu desejo seria uma variável,que iria conter o id do usuário que esta logado no momento.

Comment: @Noscin Melhore sua pergunta, oque realmente deseja fazer? Qual a variável que será utilizada? O código está completo?

Comment: Obrigado por tentarem me ajudar na consulta eu consegui resolver colocando    $data = Event::where('userid', $user)->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom eu costumo criar de forma um pouco diferente isso, acho mais intuitivo e fácil de entender e manipular, você pode usar como achar melhor:

Adicione no início do arquivo os usos das classes:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Event;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    ...
```

Crie as variáveis que serão usadas para acessar os `Models`, e as atribua no `__construct`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Event;
use Auth;

class HomeController extends Controller {
    private $event;

    public function __construct(Event $event){
         $this->event = $event;
    }
    ...
```

Desta forma você já pode acessar as informações do `Event` utilizando seus métodos `all()`, `find()` e afins... Note que adicionamos o `use Auth;` ao início do arquivo, com isso podemos acessar informações sobre a autenticação a qualquer momento, por exemplo:

```
public function testeFuncao(){
    $data = $this->event->find(Auth::user()->id);
    dd($data);
}
```

Ou você pode adaptar o que já tens somente adicionando o `use Auth;` no início e acessando seus atributos ao longo do seu `Controller` através do `Auth::user()->id`.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Darlei,irei utilizá-las.